# C : String manipulation with pointer

Tags: c

I come from JS and I'm still struggling to understand the notion of pointer, for that, I've created a function to lowercase a string.

```
char    *ft_strlowcase(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            str[i] = str[i] + 32;
        }       
        i++;
    }
    return (str);
}
```

Now, I want to test it and in my logic, I can pass a pointer to my function, like this :

```
int main(void)
{   
    //char  str1[] = "AbCdEfGhI"; //WORKING
    //char  *str1 = "AbCdEfGhI"; //NOT WORKING
    
   //char   *str1; //NOT WORKING
   //str1[] = "AbCdEfGhI"; //NOT WORKING

    char    *str1; //NOT WORKING
    str1 = "AbCdEfGhI"; //NOT WORKING
    
    printf("Lowercase : %s\n", str1);
    ft_strlowcase(&str1);
    printf("Uppercase : %s\n", str1); 
}
```

But it doesn't work, the only way I can make it works, is to pass an array declare in one line.
What did I miss ? Can I make it work with a pointer synthax and without any complex function (memloc...) ?

Comment: The correct syntax is `ft_strlowercase(str1);`, but `str1 = "AbCdEfGhI"` sets `str1` to point to a string literal which is not modifiable.  Your "WORKING" option is the right way to go.  You can't accomplish this within one expression.

Comment: Note that the alphabet is not guaranteed to be in order or even consecutive, nor the lowercase versions offset by 32. Use `isalpha()` and `tolower()`. The only guarantee about the printable character set is that `'0'` to `'9'` are consecutive and in order.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `char* str = "AAA";` and `char str[] = "AAA"`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Re “The only guarantee about the printable character set…”: The character set contains A-Z, a-z, 0-9, 29 graphic characters such as ! and ~, space, horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and a null character. The value of any of the aforementioned characters stored in a `char` is nonnegative.

Comment: @SergeyA The first is a pointer and the other one is an array, but there is more...

Comment: @EricPostpischil the only guarantee about *the sequence of* the printable character set... Mybaaad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct version of your call is `ft_strlowcase(str1)`. However, that still perpetrates undefined behavior because the string literal object created by `str1 = "AbCdEfGhI"` is being modified. String literals are part of the program image; modifying a string literal is *de facto* self-modifying code, whose behavior is not defined by ISO C.

This is not actually a big difference between dynamic languages and C here; ANSI Common Lisp is the same way with regard to modifying literal objects.

By the way, your C compiler should be warning you that the `ft_strlowcase(&str1)` call is ill-typed: it passes a `char **` pointer to a function which expects `char *`.

Now regarding this:

```
//char  str1[] = "AbCdEfGhI"; //WORKING
```

Yes that will work for two (and a half) reasons.

1. Firstly, `"AbCdEfGhI"` is no longer a literal object here, but only initializer syntax. The object is the `str1` array, and `""AbCdEfGhI"` specifies its size and initial contents. This `str1` array is not a string literal; it is mutable. It is well defined to do something like `str[0]++`.
2. Because `str1` is an array, the expression `&str1` produces a "pointer to array" value. But this pointer points to the same address as the first character of that array. So that is to say, because `str` is an array, `str`, `&str[0]` and `&str` are all the same pointer. The first two have the type `char *`, whereas `&str` has the type `char (*)[10]`: pointer to an array of 10 `char`.   The expression `ft_strlowcase(&str1)` still requires a diagnostic, which makes your program undefined: you are asking the compiler to convert one pointer type to an incompatible type without a cast. However, if the compiler simply emits the diagnostic and then supplies the conversion *as if* there were a cast, then you will get the apparently correct behavior.  You need `ft_strlowcase(str1)` (vastly preferred) or else `ft_strlowcase((char *) &str1)` (provide the cast, so no diagnostic is required). Programs that require a diagnostic have undefined behavior if they are translated and executed anyway!

Lastly, your `ft_strlowcase` function is verbose. More idiomatic C code looks like this, among other possibilities:

```
char *ft_strlowcase(char *str)
{
   for (char *ptr = str; *ptr; ptr++) {
     if (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z')
        *ptr += 32;
   }
   return str;
}
```

Believe it or not, is more readable to experienced C programmers, because it condenses together several well-understood, well-worn idioms into a concise clump.

In your original code, this is particularly something that should be avoided:

```
int i;
i = 0;
```

For no reason at all, you've declined an obvious opportunity to define an initialized variable:

```
int i = 0;
```

Initialization should always be preferred to assignment. They are different. Initialization means that an object is "born" into the world with a value; at no point in its program-visible existence does not not have a value. In C, we can define a local variable object without initializing it, which leaves it "indeterminately-valued". That habit creates the risk of using an indeterminately-valued object, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Minor: To avoid a magic number 32, could use `*str += 'a' - 'A';`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica worse than that - it is endless loop :)

Comment: That answer was good until the example snippet, which is very wrong.

Comment: Yes, why change my function ? It was wrong with str[i] writing ?

Comment: Re “using an indeterminately-valued object, which is undefined behavior”: Using an indeterminately valued object is not undefined behavior. “Undefined behavior” means the C standard imposes **no** requirements on the behavior; `char x; &x; printf("%d\n", x);` could print 999 even though 999 is not representable in a `char` or could trap or could result in the program calling another routine or taking an otherwise impossible branch. But when a program uses an indeterminate value, the standard requires it to have, for that use, **some** value that is representable in its type.

Comment: E.g., `char x; &x; printf("%d %d\n", x, x);` could print “0 123”—two different values, each representable in a `char`, but it could not print “999 999”.

Comment: Re “Firstly, "AbCdEfGhI" is no longer a literal object here, but only initializer syntax.”: A string literal used to initialize an array is a string literal. Per C 2018 6.4.5 6, it is used to initialize an array of static storage duration. This specification is not nullified when the string literal is used to initialize an array. Per 6.7.9 14, the string literal may be used to initialize an array. That string literal might be optimized away, but the same could be said of any other object, and that is outside the abstract model of computing used in the C standard.

Comment: @Kaz Your function definition is incorrect.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The return value has changed.

Comment: @Kaz And what? The function definition is incorrect.